# Changes in Word document by calling vbscript from batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am able to change font size and font name of a Word document when I call a vbscript (`doc2pdf.vbs`) but when I use a batch file to call the vbscript changes don't appear in the final document. I use the following code to call the vbscript file:

```
@Echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript C:\Users\John\Documents\doc2pdf\doc2pdf.vbs %1 %2
```

VBScript code:

```
    ' See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158.aspx
Const wdFormatPDF = 17  ' PDF format. 
Const wdFormatXPS = 18  ' XPS format. 

Const WdDoNotSaveChanges = 0

Dim arguments
Set arguments = WScript.Arguments

' Make sure that there are one or two arguments
Function CheckUserArguments()
  If arguments.Unnamed.Count < 1 Or arguments.Unnamed.Count > 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Use:"
    WScript.Echo "<script> input.doc"
    WScript.Echo "<script> input.doc output.pdf"
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End Function


' Transforms a doc to a pdf
Function DocToPdf( docInputFile, pdfOutputFile )

  Dim fileSystemObject
  Dim wordApplication
  Dim wordDocument
  Dim wordDocuments
  Dim baseFolder
  Dim r 
  Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set wordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")


  wordApplication.Visible = True
  Set wordDocuments = wordApplication.Documents

  docInputFile = fileSystemObject.GetAbsolutePathName(docInputFile)
  baseFolder = fileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(docInputFile)
  If Len(pdfOutputFile) = 0 Then
    pdfOutputFile = fileSystemObject.GetBaseName(docInputFile) + ".pdf"

  End If

  If Len(fileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(pdfOutputFile)) = 0 Then
    pdfOutputFile = baseFolder + "\" + pdfOutputFile
  End If

  ' Disable any potential macros of the word document.
  wordApplication.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros

  Set wordDocument = wordDocuments.Open(docInputFile)


   wordDocument.Content.Select
  wordApplication.Selection.Font.Size = 12
  wordApplication.Selection.Font.Name = "Lucida Console"
  ' See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221597.aspx 
  wordDocument.SaveAs docInputFile,word
  wordDocument.SaveAs pdfOutputFile, wdFormatPDF
  wordDocument.Close WdDoNotSaveChanges
  wordApplication.Quit WdDoNotSaveChanges

  Set wordApplication = Nothing
  Set fileSystemObject = Nothing

End Function

' Execute script
Call CheckUserArguments()
If arguments.Unnamed.Count = 2 Then
 Call DocToPdf( arguments.Unnamed.Item(0), arguments.Unnamed.Item(1) )
Else
 Call DocToPdf( arguments.Unnamed.Item(0), "" )
End If

Set arguments = Nothing
```

Comment: Probably need to see the content of the `vbscript` to know if it's maybe returning that the font you specified is invalid or doesn't exist on the machine, order of parameters etc.  Basically, needs more info...

Comment: vbscript runs as expected from the cmd and exports the right final document.I updated my post with the vbscript code.

Comment: i found a solution,my input file can't save any changes so i made a copy of the input document and edited that one.

Comment: What arguments to you pass to the batch file?